# Microsoft Excel Notification from Add-on

Tags: excel, notifications

I am building an add-on for Microsoft Excel. I would like to see a notification popping up displaying name of the company whenever the add-on is added to MS Excel.

I tried using xlcAlert, But it demands user interaction (The user needs to click "OK").

I would like to use some banner, which comes for a second or two and then banishes away.

Please guide for the same.

Answer (score 0):

How about a form which loads when the add-in does, and then unloads after a set interval?

Comment: Hi Diem, 
I didn't get you. What actually you mean by a form ?
I will be using the Excel4 function to call objects at the time of loading, I will pleased if you can help in those terms.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Excel4 functions, I'm afraid, so you may be approaching this in a way which wouldn't support the form.

What I was thinking was that you could build a simple form to display (via the VBA IDE) which just held a picture / some text.